# "polling ignores commits with certain messages" does not work for multi-branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have been trying to use Multi branch pipeline job. I want to skip the build job as soon as I find some text pattern as `skip_ci` in the commit message. I am able to achieve it in a simple pipeline job but the same does not work for multibranch pipeline.

I am using Add drop downs functionality "Polling ignores commits with certain messages"  Excluded Messages : `(?s).*skip_ci.*`

GIT Client plugin : 2.4.6
GIT plugin : 3.3.0

Is there something I am missing, or any other way I can achieve it?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Brij

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an open bug in Jenkins for the same.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36195